# Oracle error "too many values", must be solved with nested SELECTs

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, select

I have hit upon a "too many values" error in Oracle, when working with some intricate nested SELECTs.

A simplified description of my problem, on a toy problem describing the hierarchy in a company. There are two tables:

- **ACG_EMPLOYEES**, which lists all the employees

[image]

- **ACG_BOSS_OF**, which simply lists who (**b_id**) is the boss of whom (**e_id**)

[image]

I can do

```
SELECT b_id as boss,
             LTRIM(MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(e_id,','))
             KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY curr),',') as minion
FROM (SELECT b_id,
             e_id,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b_id ORDER BY e_id) AS curr,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b_id ORDER BY e_id) -1 AS prev
      FROM acg_boss_of)
GROUP BY b_id
CONNECT BY prev = PRIOR curr AND b_id = PRIOR b_id
START WITH curr = 1
```

to get the list of "minions" for every employee which is not a leaf in the hierarchy:
[image]

But let's say I also want to get other fields from the **ACG_EMPLOYEES** table, in this case the **name** for each boss:

[image]

I have tried

```
SELECT 
emp.name, 
(SELECT b_id as boss,
             LTRIM(MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(e_id,','))
             KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY curr),',') as minion
FROM (SELECT b_id,
             e_id,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b_id ORDER BY e_id) AS curr,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b_id ORDER BY e_id) -1 AS prev
      FROM acg_boss_of)
GROUP BY b_id
CONNECT BY prev = PRIOR curr AND b_id = PRIOR b_id
START WITH curr = 1) minion
FROM acg_employees emp
```

but I get the "too many values" error I mentioned.

I have seen some suggestions for solving this kind of issue; however, I cannot use any of them, since this statement will be used in a Product Lifecycle Management app for which this must be defined as a single SELECT, no matter how complicated (ok, I could use JOINs as well, but no stored procedures or such).

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: what means single select? no Joins?

Comment: @APC It's Oracle Database 11g Release 11.1.0.7.0 - 64bit.

Comment: @Florin Sorry, it was a bit unclear. I've updated my post: I can use JOINs and such, but no stored procedures, for instance. This SELECT will be part of a view the app creates. (Also: nice to see fellow compatriots on SO! :-) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a join?

```
SELECT 
  minion.boss,
  emp.name, 
  minion.minion
FROM acg_employees emp 
JOIN    
    (SELECT b_id as boss,
                 LTRIM(MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(e_id,','))
                 KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY curr),',') as minion
    FROM (SELECT b_id,
                 e_id,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b_id ORDER BY e_id) AS curr,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b_id ORDER BY e_id) -1 AS prev
          FROM acg_boss_of)
    GROUP BY b_id
    CONNECT BY prev = PRIOR curr AND b_id = PRIOR b_id
    START WITH curr = 1) minion
ON (minion.boss=emp.e_id)
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! I couldn't see the forest for the trees anymore, can't believe it didn't occur to me! :D

Comment: my problem is somewhat similar http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137336/select-multiple-columns-from-subquery-connect-by if u may help