# Select multiple columns from subquery - Connect by

Tags: oracle, join, oracle-11g

I have a table which manages folder structure. Hence it has a parent-child relationship.  We trigger a query to sum all documents in the complete heirarchy:

```
   SELECT  folder_name name,
      document_count,
      (SELECT SUM(e2.document_count) 
        FROM       folder_mapping e2      START WITH e2.folder_mapping_id       = e1.folder_mapping_id CONNECT BY prior e2.folder_mapping_id = e2.parent_folder_mapping_id
      )
      sum_sal
    FROM
      folder_mapping e1
```

Now I have a requirement to calculate the sum of one more column

```
    SELECT  folder_name name,
      document_count,
      (SELECT SUM(e2.document_count), **sum(e2.folder_count)**

        FROM       folder_mapping e2      START WITH e2.folder_mapping_id       = e1.folder_mapping_id CONNECT BY prior e2.folder_mapping_id = e2.parent_folder_mapping_id
      )
      sum_sal
    FROM
      folder_mapping e1
```

This query throws error:>ORA-00913: too many values.

But what can be done to achieve the same?

Database structure with data:
[image]

Intended output:
[image]

Query with help of JSapkota

```
SELECT
  fm.folder_mapping_id,
  fm_main.folder_name,
  fm.Total_Doc_Count,
  fm.Total_Folder_Count,
  --  fm.shared_flag
  DECODE(fm.shared_flag, fm_main.shared_flag
  ||'', (DECODE(fm.shared_flag, '0', 'Not Shared', '1', 'Fully Shared',
  'Partially Shared')), 'Partially Shared') shared_flag
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      folder_mapping_id,
      SUM(document_count) Total_Doc_Count,
      SUM(folder_count) Total_Folder_Count,
      SUM(SHARED_FLAG) SHARED_FLAG,
      SUM(attachment_flag) attachment_flag
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          CONNECT_BY_ROOT folder_mapping_id AS folder_mapping_id,
          document_count,
          folder_count,
          SHARED_FLAG,
          attachment_flag
        FROM
          (
            SELECT
              *
            FROM
              folder_mapping
            WHERE
              organization_id='Org_498'
          )
          --where organization_id='Org_498'
          CONNECT BY PRIOR folder_mapping_id = parent_folder_mapping_id
      )
    GROUP BY
      folder_mapping_id
  )
  fm,
  (
    SELECT
      folder_mapping_id,
      document_count,
      folder_name,
      folder_count,
      SHARED_FLAG
    FROM
      folder_mapping
    WHERE
      organization_id='Org_498'
  )
  fm_main
WHERE
  fm_main.folder_mapping_id = fm.folder_mapping_id
ORDER BY
  fm.folder_mapping_id;
```

With input as follows:
[image]

Current output is:
[image]

The output is pretty much OK except the fact that we want `root9` to be displayed as fully shared since it is a subfolder of `root8` which is fully shared.

Convention followed for shared flag
 --0 - not  shared
 --1 - fully shared
 --2 - partially shared

In case a folder is fully shared its subfolders are fully shared as well.

In case a folder is partially shared or fully shared its parent is partially shared.

Insert queries:

```
Insert into     FOLDER_MAPPING (FOLDER_MAPPING_ID,FOLDER_NAME,FOLDER_FILENET_ID,PARENT_FOLDER_MAPPING_ID,FOLDER_COUNT,DOCUMENT_COUNT,SHARED_FLAG,ATTACHMENT_FLAG,ORGANIZATION_ID,CREATED_DATE,CREATED_BY,MODIFIED_DATE,MODIFIED_BY,TYPE) values (1,'root1','111',0,2,3,'0','0','Org_498',to_timestamp('02-MAY-16 03.06.24.352000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),'11',to_timestamp('02-MAY-16 03.06.24.352000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),'1','1');
Insert into FOLDER_MAPPING (FOLDER_MAPPING_ID,FOLDER_NAME,FOLDER_FILENET_ID,PARENT_FOLDER_MAPPING_ID,FOLDER_COUNT,DOCUMENT_COUNT,SHARED_FLAG,ATTACHMENT_FLAG,ORGANIZATION_ID,CREATED_DATE,CREATED_BY,MODIFIED_DATE,MODIFIED_BY,TYPE) values (2,'root2','111',1,2,33,'0','0','Org_498',to_timestamp('02-MAY-16 03.06.24.352000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),'11',to_timestamp('02-MAY-16 03.06.24.352000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),'1','1');
Insert into FOLDER_MAPPING (FOLDER_MAPPING_ID,FOLDER_NAME,FOLDER_FILENET_ID,PARENT_FOLDER_MAPPING_ID,FOLDER_COUNT,DOCUMENT_COUNT,SHARED_FLAG,ATTACHMENT_FLAG,ORGANIZATION_ID,CREATED_DATE,CREATED_BY,MODIFIED_DATE,MODIFIED_BY,TYPE) values (3,'root3','111',1,2,1,'0','0','Org_498',to_timestamp('02-MAY-16 03.06.24.352000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),'11',to_timestamp('02-MAY-16 03.06.24.352000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),'1','1');
Insert into FOLDER_MAPPING (FOLDER_MAPPING_ID,FOLDER_NAME,FOLDER_FILENET_ID,PARENT_FOLDER_MAPPING_ID,FOLDER_COUNT,DOCUMENT_COUNT,SHARED_FLAG,ATTACHMENT_FLAG,ORGANIZATION_ID,CREATED_DATE,CREATED_BY,MODIFIED_DATE,MODIFIED_BY,TYPE) values (4,'root4','111',2,2,2,'0','0','Org_498',to_timestamp('02-MAY-16 03.06.24.352000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),'11',to_timestamp('02-MAY-16 03.06.24.352000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),'1','1');
Insert into FOLDER_MAPPING (FOLDER_MAPPING_ID,FOLDER_NAME,FOLDER_FILENET_ID,PARENT_FOLDER_MAPPING_ID,FOLDER_COUNT,DOCUMENT_COUNT,SHARED_FLAG,ATTACHMENT_FLAG,ORGANIZATION_ID,CREATED_DATE,CREATED_BY,MODIFIED_DATE,MODIFIED_BY,TYPE) values (5,'root5','111',3,2,1,'0','0','Org_498',to_timestamp('02-MAY-16 03.06.24.352000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),'11',to_timestamp('02-MAY-16 03.06.24.352000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),'1','1');
Insert into FOLDER_MAPPING (FOLDER_MAPPING_ID,FOLDER_NAME,FOLDER_FILENET_ID,PARENT_FOLDER_MAPPING_ID,FOLDER_COUNT,DOCUMENT_COUNT,SHARED_FLAG,ATTACHMENT_FLAG,ORGANIZATION_ID,CREATED_DATE,CREATED_BY,MODIFIED_DATE,MODIFIED_BY,TYPE) values (6,'root6','111',5,2,1,'0','0','Org_498',to_timestamp('02-MAY-16 03.06.24.352000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),'11',to_timestamp('02-MAY-16 03.06.24.352000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),'1','1');
Insert into FOLDER_MAPPING (FOLDER_MAPPING_ID,FOLDER_NAME,FOLDER_FILENET_ID,PARENT_FOLDER_MAPPING_ID,FOLDER_COUNT,DOCUMENT_COUNT,SHARED_FLAG,ATTACHMENT_FLAG,ORGANIZATION_ID,CREATED_DATE,CREATED_BY,MODIFIED_DATE,MODIFIED_BY,TYPE) values (7,'root7','111',6,2,1,'0','0','Org_498',to_timestamp('02-MAY-16 03.06.24.352000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),'11',to_timestamp('02-MAY-16 03.06.24.352000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),'1','1');
Insert into FOLDER_MAPPING (FOLDER_MAPPING_ID,FOLDER_NAME,FOLDER_FILENET_ID,PARENT_FOLDER_MAPPING_ID,FOLDER_COUNT,DOCUMENT_COUNT,SHARED_FLAG,ATTACHMENT_FLAG,ORGANIZATION_ID,CREATED_DATE,CREATED_BY,MODIFIED_DATE,MODIFIED_BY,TYPE) values (8,'root8','111',7,2,1,'1','0','Org_498',to_timestamp('02-MAY-16 03.06.24.352000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),'11',to_timestamp('02-MAY-16 03.06.24.352000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),'1','1');
Insert into FOLDER_MAPPING (FOLDER_MAPPING_ID,FOLDER_NAME,FOLDER_FILENET_ID,PARENT_FOLDER_MAPPING_ID,FOLDER_COUNT,DOCUMENT_COUNT,SHARED_FLAG,ATTACHMENT_FLAG,ORGANIZATION_ID,CREATED_DATE,CREATED_BY,MODIFIED_DATE,MODIFIED_BY,TYPE) values (9,'root9','111',8,2,1,'0','1','Org_498',to_timestamp('02-MAY-16 03.06.24.352000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),'11',to_timestamp('02-MAY-16 03.06.24.352000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),'1','1');
```

Comment: Added the data, yes first query is working.. second query is not working  **ORA-00913: too many values**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> #### ORA-00913 too many values
>
> **Cause:** The SQL statement requires two sets of values equal in number. This error occurs when the second set contains more items than the first set. For example, the subquery in a WHERE or HAVING clause may return too many columns, or a VALUES or SELECT clause may return more columns than are listed in the INSERT.
>   **Action:** Check the number of items in each set and change the SQL statement to make them equal.

In your case your subquery is returning two columns to the first query expecting one column.
You can change your query as follow.

```
SELECT  folder_name name,
  document_count,
  (SELECT SUM(e2.document_count)
    FROM       folder_mapping e2      START WITH e2.folder_mapping_id       = e1.folder_mapping_id CONNECT BY prior e2.folder_mapping_id = e2.parent_folder_mapping_id
  )
  sum_sal, (SELECT SUM(e2.document_count)
    FROM       folder_mapping e2      START WITH e2.folder_mapping_id       = e1.folder_mapping_id CONNECT BY prior e2.folder_mapping_id = e2.parent_folder_mapping_id
  ) folder_count_total
FROM
  folder_mapping e1
```

That was just the fix for your error. Actually you can use the following query to get the desired output which is better(In terms of cost) than the original query.

```
SQL> desc folder_mapping;
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 FOLDER_MAPPING_ID                  NUMBER
 FOLDER_NAME                        VARCHAR2(20)
 FOLDER_FILENET_ID                  NUMBER
 PARENT_FOLDER_MAPPING_ID               NUMBER
 FOLDER_COUNT                       NUMBER
 DOCUMENT_COUNT                     NUMBER
 SHARED_FLAG                        NUMBER
 ATTACHMENT_FLAG                    NUMBER

SQL> select * from folder_mapping;

FOLDER_MAPPING_ID FOLDER_NAME          FOLDER_FILENET_ID
----------------- -------------------- -----------------
PARENT_FOLDER_MAPPING_ID FOLDER_COUNT DOCUMENT_COUNT SHARED_FLAG ATTACHMENT_FLAG
------------------------ ------------ -------------- ----------- ---------------
        4 root3                  111
               2        2          2           0           0

        1 root                    11
               0        2          3           0           0

        2 root1                  111
               1        2         33           0           0



SQL> SELECT folder_name, SUM(document_count) "Total_Doc_Count", SUM(folder_count) "Total_Folder_Count"  FROM(
   SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT folder_name as folder_name, document_count, folder_count
      FROM folder_mapping
      CONNECT BY PRIOR folder_mapping_id = parent_folder_mapping_id)
      GROUP BY folder_name;   

FOLDER_NAME      Total_Doc_Count Total_Folder_Count
-------------------- --------------- ------------------
root1                 35              4
root                  38              6
root3                  2              2

SQL>
```

Comment: JSapkota - this will be really heavy option to perform we would like something which is cost effective

Comment: actual requirement is even vast and needs to make some checks on all the columns this is a small portion of actual requirement.. So the solution i am seeking should be extensible enough to perform some actions based on level of folder in heirarchy

Comment: @Varun Please notice the edit for the better query prepared according to the information provided.

Comment: the output seems good, great effort thanks alot :)

Comment: can something be done to achieve bottom up approach as well, please check the updated question

Comment: No, consider the case that there will be only one flag in hierarchy in latest example `root8` has the flag no child and parent of it can have flag 1 or 2. Based on flag on a node in hierarchy our query should tell that parents are partially shared and children are fuly shared if particular node is fully shared(1)

Comment: any help please...

Comment: Can't see data in consumable form. Please add.

Comment: @Serg - unable to get you please elaborate...

Comment: I see only screenshots of data. Can you add input data as an SQL script? `SELECT... UNION ALL ,.. SELECT`

Comment: Updated question